# How to create a stack like ListView in Android

Tags: android

I need to create a listview that looks like Stack of list items .

The list should be similar to the one that we see in the Notification Bar  or else it should be like most recent Apps in Android L.

Can anyone help me with idea of how to implement such type of list or some sample code fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Base Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)  . You can define the element of list anyway you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ListView for the UI development and implement the suitable adapter for it.

You need to have three things:

1. Source of data which you want to display your list view.
2. Fragment/UI [List View] for displaying the data.
3. An adapter which binds data to list view.

[Check for detailed answer without fragment](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

[Tutorial with fragment and list view](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/05/android-working-with-fragments.html)